# jQuery doesn't properly update contents of the span tag

Tags: jquery

here's the example: http://jsbin.com/izegoy
problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSHZR.png

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p:eq(1)").hide().after("<span>View more</span>");
    $("span").click(function(){
        $("p:eq(1)").slideToggle(200,function(){
            if($("span").text()=="View more"){
                $("span").text("View less");
        }   else{
                $("span").text("View more");
        }
        });
    });
});
```

html:

```
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

When I update contents of the span tag, it creates the new text outside of the original span tag. It's not noticeable on the page, but only when you look at the generated source code. I have no idea, what I do wrong.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Your code seems to work: [http://jsfiddle.net/UpK9V/](http://jsfiddle.net/UpK9V/)

Comment: I'm not seeing what you are seeing, the only text being created is inside the span tags.

Comment: Works (and verified using Inspector) in Chrome 17.

Comment: Seems to work for me, generated source code: `<span>View less</span>`

Comment: It looks allright, but the source is messed up. It looks like this:    <span>View less</span>"View less"</span>

Comment: Maybe it's a jsbin thing. I pasted your code into jsFiddle and it's fine there (but I do see the issue on jsbin). http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r4tfu/

Comment: It **really** works for me. are you using chrome on your screenshot?

Comment: @j08691 same thing happens in jsfiddle http://i.imgur.com/rCCZG.png Just click it more than once and you'll get the same thing as in the image. However, when I use .html() instead of .text() it works perfectly. I just have no idea why...

Comment: @Alex Yes, I'm using chrome 17 on ubuntu 10.10. I tried to check in firefox and it works as it expected. I guess this is just chrome thing...

Comment: okay, now I was able to reproduce it with chrome. doesn't happen with firefox...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should really work fine. But you could try using the `html();` method instead:

```
$("span").html("View less");
```